# How to search for ZCatalog object names

Tags: python, dhtml, zope

I want to Search for an Object name.
If i have this Structure:
/de/myspace/media/justAnotherPdf.pdf

Then i want to Search for the name "justAnotherPdf" to find it or something like "justAnot"
I have Indexed the pdf files.

But i cant search it with TextIndexNG2 or PathIndex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this is not supported out-of-the-box. Object identifiers (`getId`) are only indexed as field values and thus can only be looked up as whole strings.

You'd need to add separate index to the catalog to support your use-case. You could add a new TextIndexNG2 index with a new name indexing just the getId method. In the ZMI, find the portal_catalog, then it's 'Indexes' tab, then on the right-hand-side you'll find a drop-down menu for adding a new index. Pick a memorable name ('fullTextId' for example) and use `getId` as the indexed attribute.

You'll need to do a reindex, but only for that index. Once added, select it in on the Indexes tab (tick the check-box) and select 'Reindex' at the bottom of that page. Now you can use this index in your custom searches with a wildcard search.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os.path
name = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(url)[1])[0]
```

explaining the code:

```
from os.path import split, splitext
url = '/de/myspace/media/justAnotherPdf.pdf'
path, name_with_ext = split(url)
name_without_ext, ext = splitext(name_with_ext)
```

Comment: Ok i understand tha. But when the User give a Search to the Script i have to go into each media Directory ;) But i have about 400+ Files in different folders...

Comment: It is just the method to extract the file name without extension, it could be encapsulated in a function and you would use it in a `os.walk` loop... =P